# How to correctly convert bmp file to tiff file? The tiff file will used in ArcMap

Tags: python, arcmap, geotiff-tiff

How to correctly convert bmp file to tiff file? The tiff file will used in ArcMap?
I use the follwing code, but the result in ArcMap is not correct. The cell size is not correct. The cell size is 1,1. But I want it be 0.0083333,0.008333.

```
img = Image.open('bmp_24.bmp').convert(
    'P', None, "FLOYDSTEINBERG", 1, 5)
    
img.save('bmp_24.tiff', format='TIFF', compression='tiff_lzw')
```

Comment: How do you know what is the cell size of the BMP image? Is there a sidecar world file (.wld of .bpw), and perhaps also a .prj file telling that the coordinate system is EPSG:4326 as you seem to suppose.

Comment: I drag the file into arcmap's layers. I can see the cell size in the properties -> source -> raster information